# Treeview with checkboxes - adding checkbox behaviour

Tags: delphi, checkbox, treeview

I am working on creating Treeview with checkboxes. I figured it out how to toggle checkboxes to nodes (`procedure ToggleTreeViewCheckBoxes`). I have added `TImageList` component with checkbox bitmaps and change `StateIndex` in `OnClick` treeview event. It works fine, but I would like to add additional behaviour to that.

I created treeview structure as an example:

- Root 1

  - Parent 1 (checkbox)

    - Child 1 (checkbox)
    - Child 2 (checkbox)
  - Parent 2 (checkbox)

    - Child 1 (checkbox)
    - Child 2 (checkbox)
- Root 2

  - Parent 1 (checkbox)

    - Child 1 (checkbox)
    - Child 2 (checkbox)
  - Parent 2 (checkbox)

    - Child 1 (checkbox)
    - Child 2 (checkbox)

Below I am attaching you sample code which I have prepared with creating treeview and adding nodes, checkboxes.

```
unit TreeViewCheckboxes;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList,
  Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure ToggleTreeViewCheckBoxes(Node:TTreeNode; cUnChecked, cChecked: Integer);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

const
  cStateUnCheck = 1;
  cStateChecked = 2;

   aRootList: Array[1..2] of String =
   (
      'Root 1',
      'Root 2'
   );

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm5 }

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
   RootNode: TTreeNode;
   ParentNode: TTreeNode;
   ChildNode: TTreeNode;
   i: Integer;
begin
   for i := 1 to High(aRootList) do
   begin
      RootNode := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, aRootList[i]);

      ParentNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(RootNode, 'Parent 1');
      ParentNode.StateIndex := 1;
      ChildNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(ParentNode, 'Child 1');
      ChildNode.StateIndex := 1;
      ChildNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(ParentNode, 'Child 2');
      ChildNode.StateIndex := 1;    

      ParentNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(RootNode, 'Parent 2');
      ParentNode.StateIndex := 1;
      ChildNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(ParentNode, 'Child 1');
      ChildNode.StateIndex := 1;
      ChildNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(ParentNode, 'Child 2');
      ChildNode.StateIndex := 1;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm5.ToggleTreeViewCheckBoxes(Node: TTreeNode; cUnChecked,
  cChecked: Integer);
begin
   if Assigned(Node) then
   begin
      if Node.StateIndex = cUnChecked then
         Node.StateIndex := cChecked
      else if Node.StateIndex = cChecked then
         Node.StateIndex := cUnChecked;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm5.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   P: TPoint;
begin
   GetCursorPos(P);
   P := TreeView1.ScreenToClient(P);
   if (htOnStateIcon in TreeView1.GetHitTestInfoAt(P.X, P.Y)) then
      ToggleTreeViewCheckBoxes(TreeView1.Selected, cStateUnCheck, cStateChecked);
end;    
end.
```

Questions:

1) How can I do something like that: If I click on any `Parent` checkbox node, all child nodes are unchecked?

2) Do you know any better way to dynamically add nodes and set `StateIndex` for all childs? I mean no every time use line `ChildNode.StateIndex := 1;`

Comment: Standard Win32 TreeView controls natively support checkboxes (see the [`TVS_CHECKBOXES` window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760013.aspx)), but the `TTreeView` VCL component *still to this day* does not support that feature ([RSP-15270](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15270)).

Comment: That's true, but I found it: _"You can add checkboxes to the treeview by overriding the CreateParams procedure of the TTreeView, specifying the TVS_CHECKBOXES style for the control.The result is that all nodes in the treeview will have checkboxes attached to them. In addition, the StateImages property can't be used anymore because the WC_TREEVIEW uses this imagelist internally to implement checkboxes_". I am not going add checkboxes in every node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) How can I do something like that: If I click on any Parent checkbox node, all child nodes are unchecked?

You have to manually iterate through all of the children, eg:

```
procedure TForm5.SetTreeViewCheckState(Node: TTreeNode; StateIndex: Integer; Recursive: Boolean);
begin
  Node.StateIndex := StateIndex;
  if not Recursive then Exit;
  for I := 0 to Node.Count-1 do
    SetTreeViewCheckState(Node.Item[I], StateIndex, True);
end;

procedure TForm5.ToggleTreeViewCheckBoxes(Node: TTreeNode);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(Node) then
  begin
    if Node.StateIndex = cStateUnCheck then
      SetTreeViewCheckState(Node, cStateChecked, False);
    else if Node.StateIndex = cStateChecked then
      SetTreeViewCheckState(Node, cStateUnCheck, True);
  end;
end;
```

> 2) Do you know any better way to dynamically add nodes and set StateIndex for all childs? I mean no every time use line ChildNode.StateIndex := 1;

Sorry, but that is the only way to do it.  But you can wrap it in a function:

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RootNode: TTreeNode;
  ParentNode: TTreeNode;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(aRootList) to High(aRootList) do
  begin
    RootNode := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, aRootList[i]);

    ParentNode := AddChildNodeWithState(RootNode, 'Parent 1');
    AddChildNodeWithState(ParentNode, 'Child 1');
    AddChildNodeWithState(ParentNode, 'Child 2');

    ParentNode := AddChildNodeWithState(RootNode, 'Parent 2');
    AddChildNodeWithState(ParentNode, 'Child 1');
    AddChildNodeWithState(ParentNode, 'Child 2');
  end;
end;

function TForm5.AddChildNodeWithState(AParentNode: TTreeNode, const ACaption: String; AStateIndex: Integer = 1): TTreeNode;
begin
  Result := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(AParentNode, ACaption);
  Result.StateIndex := AStateIndex;
end;
```

Or, you can create a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_helper) (which you can use for the toggling logic as well):

```
type
  TTreeNodeHelper = class helper for TTreeNode
  public
    function AddChildWithState(const ACaption: string; AStateIndex: Integer = 1): TTreeNode;
    procedure SetCheckState(StateIndex: Integer; Recursive: Boolean);
    procedure ToggleCheckState;
  end;

function TTreeNodeHelper.AddChildWithState(const ACaption: string; AStateIndex: Integer = 1): TTreeNode;
begin
  Result := Self.TreeView.Items.AddChild(Self, ACaption);
  Result.StateIndex := AStateIndex;
end;

procedure TTreeNodeHelper.SetCheckState(StateIndex: Integer; Recursive: Boolean);
begin
  Self.StateIndex := StateIndex;
  if not Recursive then Exit;
  for I := 0 to Self.Count-1 do
    Self.Item[I].SetCheckState(StateIndex, True);
end;

procedure TTreeNodeHelper.ToggleCheckState;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Self.StateIndex = cStateUnCheck then
    SetCheckState(cStateChecked, False);
  else if Self.StateIndex = cStateChecked then
    SetCheckState(cStateUnCheck, True);
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RootNode: TTreeNode;
  ParentNode: TTreeNode;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(aRootList) to High(aRootList) do
  begin
    RootNode := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, aRootList[i]);

    ParentNode := RootNode.AddChildWithState('Parent 1');
    ParentNode.AddChildWithState('Child 1');
    ParentNode.AddChildWithState('Child 2');

    ParentNode := RootNode.AddChildWithState('Parent 2');
    ParentNode.AddChildWithState('Child 1');
    ParentNode.AddChildWithState('Child 2');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TPoint;
begin
  GetCursorPos(P);
  P := TreeView1.ScreenToClient(P);
  if (htOnStateIcon in TreeView1.GetHitTestInfoAt(P.X, P.Y)) then
    TreeView1.GetNodeAt(P.X, P.Y).ToggleCheckState;
end;
```

If you are using an older version of Delphi that does not support class helpers, you can derive a class from `TTreeNode` instead and use it with the TreeView's [`OnCreateNodeClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.OnCreateNodeClass) event, eg:

```
type
  TMyTreeNode = class(TTreeNode)
  public
    function AddChildWithState(const ACaption: string; AStateIndex: Integer = 1): TTreeNode;
    procedure SetCheckState(StateIndex: Integer; Recursive: Boolean);
    procedure ToggleCheckState;
  end;

function TMyTreeNode.AddChildWithState(const ACaption: string; AStateIndex: Integer = 1): TTreeNode;
begin
  Result := Self.TreeView.Items.AddChild(Self, ACaption);
  Result.StateIndex := AStateIndex;
end;

procedure TMyTreeNode.SetCheckState(StateIndex: Integer; Recursive: Boolean);
begin
  Self.StateIndex := StateIndex;
  if not Recursive then Exit;
  for I := 0 to Self.Count-1 do
    TMyTreeNode(Self.Item[I]).SetCheckState(StateIndex, True);
end;

procedure TMyTreeNode.ToggleCheckBoxes;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Self.StateIndex = cStateUnCheck then
    SetCheckBoxes(cStateChecked, cStateUnChecked);
  else if Self.StateIndex = cStateChecked then
    SetCheckBoxes(cStateUnCheck, cStateUnChecked);
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RootNode: TTreeNode;
  ParentNode: TTreeNode;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(aRootList) to High(aRootList) do
  begin
    RootNode := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, aRootList[i]);

    ParentNode := TMyTreeNode(RootNode).AddChildWithState('Parent 1');
    TMyTreeNode(ParentNode).AddChildWithState('Child 1');
    TMyTreeNode(ParentNode).AddChildWithState('Child 2');

    ParentNode := TMyTreeNode(RootNode).AddChildWithState('Parent 2');
    TMyTreeNode(ParentNode).AddChildWithState('Child 1');
    TMyTreeNode(ParentNode).AddChildWithState('Child 2');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TPoint;
begin
  GetCursorPos(P);
  P := TreeView1.ScreenToClient(P);
  if (htOnStateIcon in TreeView1.GetHitTestInfoAt(P.X, P.Y)) then
    TMyTreeNode(TreeView1.GetNodeAt(P.X, P.Y)).ToggleCheckState;
end;    

procedure TForm5.TreeView1CreateNodeClass(Sender: TCustomTreeView; var NodeClass: TTreeNodeClass)
begin
  NodeClass := TMyTreeNode;
end;
```

Comment: First, thanks for your exausting and valuable response. I found one more issue with first issue (unchecking child nodes when click on parent node). **Example**: If we go to Child node and check it and next we check Parent, all childs are unchecked. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @astack: Um, that is what you asked for: "*If I click on any Parent checkbox node, **all child nodes are unchecked**.*" What do you want it to do instead? If the parent is checked then all child nodes should be checked, and if the parent is unchecked then all child nodes should be unchecked? That would make sense. Simply change the last parameter of `SetCheckBoxes()` accordingly (or remove that parameter altogether). Or, do you want all child nodes to be unchecked even if the parent is checked, but skip any child node that was previously checked? That gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: I mean: "If I click on Parent in _cStateChecked_ mode, all child nodes are unchecked". The issue is if I check some child nodes and I click on Parent in _cStateUnchecked_, all child nodes are unchecked. In this case child nodes should be independent of the parent and I should be able to keep their checked state. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: If a parent node is *currently* checked and a click unchecks it, all of its child nodes should be unchecked, right? The code shown does exactly that. If a parent node is *currently* unchecked and a click checks it, its child nodes that are *already* checked should *remain* checked, right? What about child nodes that are *currently* unchecked? Should they *toggle* to checked, or *remain* unchecked? If the former, set the second parameter of `SetCheckBoxes()` to `cStateChecked` when toggling the parent to checked. If the latter, just toggle the parent by itself, ignore its child nodes altogether

Comment: _Right - if the parent node is currently checked, after click on it all child nodes should be unchecked(it works)_, but if the parent node is currently unchecked and we click check, we shouldn't check all child nodes but we should keep their state(it works). The one issue is just in one case, **example:**  Parent node is _unchecked_ but one of the child in this parent node is _checked_ and we click on _unchecked_ Parent Node to check it - in this case all **child nodes** are _unchecked_ but **we should keep their state**. Hopefully now it will be clear for you.